# Transfer ownership web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am creating a dapp to transfer ownership of the contract from one address to another using testrpc. However,I keep encountering this problem. I have tried using sentransaction method to do perform this ownership change.Perhaps I'm calling the exchange in a wrong manner.
Solidity version 0.4.4
web3 "version": "0.20.2"

```
web3.js:3127 Uncaught Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
at Object.InvalidResponse (web3.js:3127)
at RequestManager.send (web3.js:6332)
at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (web3.js:5066)
at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (web3.js:4122)
at SolidityFunction.execute (web3.js:4208)
at transferOwnership (luxcure_manu.html:309)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (luxcure_manu.html:378
```

Full solidity contract as of yet.

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

  // TODO: Hash of the cert through IPFS Hash
  // Transfer ownership of smart contract
contract LuxSecure {
address public contract_owner;           //Manufacturer/owner
//string public current_owner;    //Current Owner of good
bytes32 public model;            //Model
mapping(uint => address) public owners; //list of owners
uint256 public owners_count;
bytes32 public status;           // (Public(Owned by no one), Private(Bought by another entity),stolen(Stolen from public or private))
bytes32 public date_manufactured;   //Time

// Set manufacturer of the Good RUN ONCE ONLY
function manufacturer() public{
  if(owners_count == 0){
  contract_owner = msg.sender;
}
}

//Modifier that only allows owner of the bag to Smart Contract AKA Good to use the function
modifier onlyOwner(){
  require(msg.sender == contract_owner);
  _;
}
 // Add a new product to the blockchain with a new serial
function addNewGoods(bytes32 _model,bytes32 _status, bytes32 _date_manufactured) public returns(bool made) {//Declare Goods struct
setOwner(msg.sender);
model = _model;
status = _status;
date_manufactured =  _date_manufactured;
return true;
}

//This function transfer ownership of contract from one entity to another
function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner(){
  require(_newOwner != address(0));
  contract_owner = _newOwner;
}

//Set the KEY to uint256 and VALUE owner Ethereum Address
function setOwner(address owner)public{
   owners_count += 1 ;
   owners[owners_count] = owner;
}

//Get the previous owner in the mappings
function previousOwner()constant public returns(address){
  if(owners_count != 0){
  uint256 previous_owner = owners_count - 1;
  return owners[previous_owner];
}
}

// Getter Methods
function getManufacturer() constant public returns(address){
  return contract_owner;
}

function getCurrentOwner() constant public returns(address){
  return owners[owners_count] ;
}

function getOwnerCount() constant public returns(uint256){
  return owners_count;
}

function getModel() constant public returns(bytes32){
  return model;
}

function getStatus() constant public returns(bytes32){
return status;
}

function getDateManufactured() constant public returns(bytes32){
  return date_manufactured;
}

}// end of LuxSecure
```

Javascript to perform the transfer of ownership

```
function transferOwnership(){
var account_to_transfer = document.getElementById("ethereumaddress").value;
contract.transferOwnership(account_to_transfer,{
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
    gas:4000000
});
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full contract? Also, what version of web3js are you using?

Comment: Just added more information about the contract and web3js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any particular mistake in your code. Maybe a bad formatting on the front-side, but can't guess for sure as we have partial front here.

I don't know if it will be some help but sometimes, using truffle, it happened to me to have some functions that returned bad opcode from testrpc/ganache-cli while no apparent error was in the code.

Deleting the ABI, recompiling the smart-contracts to get a brand new ABI and then redeploying the contracts solved the problem.

Comment: Did you try deploying on a private network to solve this problem? This is an inherent problem with testrpc?

Comment: i always deploy on a local private network first then on a testnet and only once the code completely tested deploying on the main net.

The opcode errors i was getting and talking about were usualy when deploying on private local network. I don't know if it's testrpc or the ABI that was failing but deleting the ABI and regenerating the file with compiling with truffle solved the problem.